# The requested operation requires elevation even after running visual studio as Administrator

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to run and resize OSK from my winform application but I am getting this error:

> The requested operation requires elevation.

I am running visual studio as administrator.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.StartInfo.FileName = "c:\\windows\\system32\\osk.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "";
process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "c:\\";

process.Start(); // **ERROR HERE**
process.WaitForInputIdle();
SetWindowPos(process.MainWindowHandle,
this.Handle, // Parent Window
this.Left, // Keypad Position X
this.Top + 20, // Keypad Position Y
panelButtons.Width, // Keypad Width
panelButtons.Height, // Keypad Height
SWP_SHOWWINDOW | SWP_NOZORDER); // Show Window and Place on Top
SetForegroundWindow(process.MainWindowHandle);
```

However,

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("osk.exe");
```

Works just fine but it wont let me resize the keyboard

Comment: Have you tried running in "Release" mode? ie running your program exe? For running your exe as administrator you can use `startInfo.Verb = "runas";`

Answer (score 3):

`process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false` will prohibit you from doing what you want to do. `osk.exe` is a bit special as only one instance can run at a time. So you must let the os handle the startup (`UseShellExecute` must be true).

> (...) Works just fine but it wont let me resize the keyboard

Just make sure that `process.MainWindowHandle` is not `IntPtr.Zero`. Could take a while though, your'e not allowed to ask the process instance with `process.WaitForInputIdle()`, probably because the proc is run by the os. You could poll the handle though and then run your code. like this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
// process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
// process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
// process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.StartInfo.FileName = "c:\\windows\\system32\\osk.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "";
process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "c:\\";

process.Start(); // **ERROR WAS HERE**
//process.WaitForInputIdle();

//Wait for handle to become available
while(process.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
    Task.Delay(10).Wait();

SetWindowPos(process.MainWindowHandle,
this.Handle, // Parent Window
this.Left, // Keypad Position X
this.Top + 20, // Keypad Position Y
panelButtons.Width, // Keypad Width
panelButtons.Height, // Keypad Height
SWP_SHOWWINDOW | SWP_NOZORDER); // Show Window and Place on Top
SetForegroundWindow(process.MainWindowHandle);
```

Due note: use of `Wait()` (or `Thread.Sleep`); should be very limited in WinForms, it renders the ui thread unresponsive. You should probably use `Task.Run(async () => ...` here instead, to be able to use `await Task.Delay(10)`, but that's a different story and complicates the code slightly.